# Custom initiations in Swift - Is there a way to 'not' initialize certain properties in a method?

Tags: swift, xcode, initialization

So my question is: Is there a way to create a custom initializer like below without initializing the other properties in the structure? I get an error within the custom initialization below because I am not giving values to the other two properties in the structure.

So my goal would be to create an instance of this structure, and only give values to three properties.
 EX:
    var starbucks = Coffee(caffeineAmountMg: 1200, countryOfOrigin: "South America", taste: "bad")

I just started coding a few days ago, so I apologize if there is a big lapse in my logic here, just trying to test out a few different things to make sure I understand everything I've learned so far.

```
struct Coffee {
var caffeineAmountMg: Int

init(caffeineAmountMg: Int) {
    self.caffeineAmountMg = caffeineAmountMg
    caffeineAmountG = caffeineAmountMg / 1000
}
var caffeineAmountG: Int

init(caffeineAmountG: Int) {
    self.caffeineAmountG = caffeineAmountG
    caffeineAmountMg = caffeineAmountG * 1000
}


var countryOfOrigin: String
var taste: String
}
```

Comment: You should use `self.` more consistently. But regardless, you shouldn't cache unit conversions like this. You'll inevitably run into a situation where you update a value as represented by one unit, but forget to update its representation in other units. It's much better to just have one canonical base unit, and convert to other units as necessary, using computed properties. I'd even suggest using Foundation's `Measurement` api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, it can be done. The key to creating and initializing an object in Swift is to give all the variables values, i.e., initialize all of the object's variables to contain a valid value. The compiler will complain otherwise.

If you're not sure of the value of a certain variable, or if you would like to initialize a set of other variables, you can declare the unwanted variable as `Optional`, for ex.

```
var caffeineAmountG: Int?
```

An Optional variable means that it can either contain a valid value (`Int` in this case), or it can contain `nil`. In your `init` method, if you do not give any value to your Optional variable, it will be, by default initialised to `nil` automatically by the compiler.

So just as you wanted, you can have your struct initialised in a simple manner like so:

```
struct Coffee {

    var caffeineAmountMg: Int
    var caffeineAmountG: Int? //Considered caffeineAmountG = nil

    var countryOfOrigin: String
    var taste: String

    init(caffeineAmountMg:Int, countryOfOrigin:String, taste:String) {
        self.caffeineAmountMg = caffeineAmountMg
        self.countryOfOrigin = countryOfOrigin
        self.taste = taste
    }
}

let coffee = Coffee(caffeineAmountMg: 32320, countryOfOrigin: "Country", taste: "Taste")
```

---

You can also - instead of initialising the variable to `nil` - provide any default value like this *(without declaring it `Optional`)*:

```
var caffeineAmountG: Int = 0
```

*Or you can compute it (`caffeineAmountG`) as you initialise your other variables:*

```
init(caffeineAmountMg:Int, countryOfOrigin:String, taste:String) {
    self.caffeineAmountMg = caffeineAmountMg
    self.countryOfOrigin = countryOfOrigin
    self.taste = taste
    self.caffeineAmountG = self.caffeineAmountMg / 1000 //Converting Milligram to Gram
}
```

---

So according to the above `init` method, if we print the initialized object, it will contain the following values:

```
Coffee(caffeineAmountMg: 32320,
caffeineAmountG: 32,
countryOfOrigin: "Country",
taste: "Taste")
```

Comment: Ahh!! This is really easy to understand, thank you. I just started coding so the simple solution is much appreciated. Thank you very much!! :D

Answer (score 2):

One solution in this particular case is to store the quantity in a normalized form, and compute the other form(s). Let's say we store the quantity is milligrams. So:

```
struct Coffee {

    init(caffeineAmountMg: Int, countryOfOrigin: String, taste: String) {
        self.caffeineAmountMg = caffeineAmountMg
        self.countryOfOrigin = countryOfOrigin
        self.taste = taste
    }

    convenience init(caffeineAmountG: Int, countryOfOrigin: String, taste: String) {
        self.init(caffeineAmountMg: caffeineAmountG * 1000, countryOfOrigin: countryOfOrigin, taste: taste)
    }

    var caffeineAmountMg: Int

    var caffeineAmountG: Int {
        get { return caffeineAmountMg / 1000 }
        set { caffeineAmountMg = newValue * 1000 }
    }

    var countryOfOrigin: String
    var taste: String
}

let cup = Coffee(caffeineAmountG: 1, countryOfOrigin: "South America is actually a continent", taste: "bad")
```

A variation on this style is to factor out the unit conversion into a separate type:

```
struct Mass {
    let µg: Int
    var mg: Int { return µg / 1_000 }
    var g: Int { return µg / 1_000_000 }

    private init(µg: Int) { self.µg = µg }

    static func µg(_ µg: Int) -> Mass { return Mass(µg: µg) }
    static func mg(_ mg: Int) -> Mass { return Mass(µg: mg * 1_000) }
    static func g(_ g: Int) -> Mass { return Mass(µg: g * 1_000_000) }
}

struct Coffee {

    init(caffeineAmount: Mass, countryOfOrigin: String, taste: String) {
        self.caffeineAmount = caffeineAmount
        self.countryOfOrigin = countryOfOrigin
        self.taste = taste
    }

    var caffeineAmount: Mass
    var countryOfOrigin: String
    var taste: String
}

let cup = Coffee(caffeineAmount: .mg(10), countryOfOrigin: "South America is actually a continent", taste: "bad")
```

Comment: Feel pretty stupid about the 'South America is a country' thing..thank you for the correction haha. And thank you so much for the answer!!

So when you say 'normalized form' what exactly do you mean by that? I tried to google around but couldn't really find an answer that made sense for this situation.

I'm also a little bit confused as to why there are two custom initializations in the first example..the first init, and then the convenience init. If you don't mind, could you explain why this is the case?

Comment: You could use [`Measurement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement) rather than creating the `Mass` struct

Comment: A “normalized form” means a form that stores all the relevant information in a single way and no redundant information. So instead of possibly storing the mass in two ways simultaneously (in both mg and g), we store it in a single way (just mg) and convert to/from the other form (g) on demand. Since you chose to represent the mass as `Int` (a somewhat questionable decision), mg is a better normalized form than g, because converting mg to g loses information (1100 mg gets rounded to 1 g) but converting from g to mg loses no information.

Comment: Ah, okay that makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much! I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions! :)

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on @Paulw11 comment to use `Measurement`.

This keeps your exact API. You could improve things by making `caffeineAmount` public, and getting rid of `caffeineAmountMg` or `caffeineAmountG`.

```
struct Coffee {
    var caffeineAmountMg: Int {
        get { return Int(caffeineAmount.converted(to: UnitMass.milligrams).value) }
        set { caffeineAmount = Measurement(value: Double(newValue), unit: UnitMass.milligrams) }
    }

    init(caffeineAmountMg: Int, countryOfOrigin: String, taste: String) {
        self.caffeineAmount = Measurement(value: Double(caffeineAmountMg), unit: UnitMass.milligrams)
        self.countryOfOrigin = countryOfOrigin
        self.taste = taste
    }

    var caffeineAmountG: Int {
        get { return Int(caffeineAmount.converted(to: UnitMass.grams).value) }
        set { caffeineAmount = Measurement(value: Double(newValue), unit: UnitMass.grams) }
    }

    init(caffeineAmountG: Int, countryOfOrigin: String, taste: String) {
        caffeineAmount = Measurement(value: Double(caffeineAmountG), unit: UnitMass.grams)
        self.countryOfOrigin = countryOfOrigin
        self.taste = taste
    }

    var countryOfOrigin: String
    var taste: String

    private var caffeineAmount: Measurement<UnitMass>
}
```